# Uploading images to google cloud storage with multer and nodejs getting error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, multer

== updated question on 9/9 ===

Tried to use Multer directly without the Middleware like before and using Postman to upload the images.

From Nodejs, req return

```
  files: [Object: null prototype] {
    imagebackup: [ [Object] ],
    imagebanner: [ [Object] ]
  },
```

However, when I console req.file
it showing "undefined"

**new file-routers.js as below:**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const router = express.Router();
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.MemoryStorage,
}).fields([{name: "imagebackup"}, {name: "imagebanner"}]);


router.post('/file', (req, res)=>{
  
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    console.log(req) // return Files [object null]
    console.log(req.file) // return "undefined" 

    if(err) throw err;
  })
    
});
```

**Weird thing is, by using upload.single(), everything works just fine. **

## ==

==
===== Here is the old code & can't solve it =====
It return an error

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\carchaw\Documents\pfx_template_generator_api\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\carchaw\Documents\pfx_template_generator_api\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at Busboy.emit (node:events:379:20)
```

On the form submit, I need upload 2 images from different input field, create new prefix on GCS, and also store the image's name and other's details to be sent in request.body.

From the front-end part, I using Fetch as below:

```
const getFormContianer = document.getElementById("get_form")
 async function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let dataForm = new FormData(e.target)
    
   await fetch(file_api, {
        method: 'POST',    
        body: dataForm
        
    }).then((res)=>{
        return res.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log('api err: '+data);
    }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log('api err: '+ err)
    })
    
}

getFormContianer.addEventListener('submit', handleForm)
```

**index.html**

```
<form id="get_form">
<label for="video_url">video_url</label>
<input name="video_url" type="text" id="video_url" value=""><br>
<label for="image_backup">image_backup</label>
<input name="image_backup" type="file" id="image_backup" value=""><br>
<label for="image_banner">image_banner</label>
<input name="image_banner" type="file" id="image_banner" value=""><br>
</form>
<input type="submit" id="handle_submit">
```

Nodejs

**multer middleware**

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");

let processFile = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage()
}).fields([{ name: "image_backup" }, { name: "image_banner" }])

let processFileMiddleware = util.promisify(processFile);
module.exports = processFileMiddleware;
```

**handling Upload**

```
const handleUploadImages = async (req, res) =>{
  try {
    await processFile(req, res);

    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please upload a file!" });
    }

    // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
    const blob = bucket.file(newFolderPath + req.file.originalname);
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      resumable: false,
    });

    blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });

    blobStream.on("finish", async (data) => {
      // Create URL for directly file access via HTTP.
      const publicUrl = format(
        `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${newFolderPath}/${blob.name}`
      );

      try {
        // Make the file public
        await bucket.file(newFolderPath + req.file.originalname).makePublic();
      } catch {
        return res.status(500).send({
          message:
            `Uploaded the file successfully: ${newFolderPath + req.file.originalname}, but public access is denied!`,
          url: publicUrl,
        });
      }

      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + newFolderPath + req.file.originalname,
        url: publicUrl,
      });
    });

    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
    });
  }
}
```

I did use express json and urlencoded on index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); 
const config = require('./config')
const app = express()

const templates = require('./routes/templates-routes');
const files = require('./routes/files-routes');

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  


app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/api', templates.routes);
app.use('/create', files.routes);


app.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${config.port}`)
  })
```

Hope that can get some suggestion on this, thank you!

Comment: can you include in the post the console.log() output of the FormData just before the code reaches the fetch statement?

Comment: @kvicera  if you mean console.log(dataForm) ? 
is show something like this:
FormData {}
[[Prototype]]: FormData

I guess it can be console direct for the New FormData?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the tutorial that you're following?

Comment: @drauedo Here is the link: https://www.bezkoder.com/google-cloud-storage-nodejs-upload-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue after few days keep trying.

for front-end POST rest API, passing files by appending file itself and the name.

```
 function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let dataForm = new FormData(e.target)
   
    dataForm.append("image_backup", document.getElementById("image_backup").files[0]);    
    dataForm.append("image_banner", document.getElementById("image_banner").files[0]);
    dataForm.append("image_banner_name", document.getElementById("image_banner").value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''));
    dataForm.append("image_backup_name", document.getElementById("image_backup").value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''));
    
   await fetch(file_api, {
        method: 'POST',    
        body: dataForm
        
    }).then((res)=>{
        return res.json();
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log('api data: '+ data);
    }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log('api err: '+ err)
    })
    
}
```

on Nodejs

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.MemoryStorage,
}).fields([{name: "image_backup"}, {name: "image_banner"}]);

const startCreatefiles = async(req, res, next) =>{
 
  upload(req, res, (err) => {  
    
     console.log(req.body);
      console.log(req.files);
      
  })    
}
```

Then successfully get the text form data and file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `body: dataForm` declared? That error arises when you try to upload a field that is not mentioned in fields:

```
fields([{ name: "image_backup" }, { name: "image_banner" }])
```

Make sure your multipart form has these 2 fields only for uploading files.

Comment: it grab the info from the form that I posted in the index.html part. 
updated my question with the complete function on form submit!

Comment: @carolchaw can you try passing the `dataForm` itself as body in request? You don't need to stringify it iirc. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58032429/13130697)

Comment: Yes I do pass the dataForm as the body directly.  ( The Json.stringify was not being used in the code, I should remove it to avoid confusion )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this post in which they discuss the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050928/node-js-multer-error-unexpected-field/47051269).

In order to solve it they basically formatted the file that need to be uploaded.

```
formData.append("type_of_the_file", uploadfile);
```

Comment: Hi~ I did found this post before. I confirmed that my field name of the input is same as the name that I put in the Multer fields, still the same error occurs